# Android Data Binding pass different view from onClick

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding

I need to animate image2 clicking image1 using databinding.
I would like to know if exist a way to pass different view from onclick method in XML because I need image2 view.
In example below i pass view image1 but i would like to pass image2 view:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">

    <data>

        <import
            alias="v"
            type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="MainFragment" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_sky">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_one"
            android:onClick="@{(v)-> viewModel.rotateImage(v)}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_two"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="image1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please try to modify the following code:

```
  <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            ...
            android:onClick="@{(v)-> viewModel.rotateImage(image2)}"
            ... />
```

Comment: Yes it's working. I believe was totally different and complicate. Thanks

Comment: if you havу like "sw_switch", use it as viewModel.rotateImage(swSwitch)}